# SQL Server : LENGTH() inside of REPLICATE()

Tags: sql-server, replicate

I have a SQL Server table with the columns `Lvl` and `Title`. I need to insert a "-" in front of the title for every character in the `Lvl` field.

As an example: If `Lvl = 111` the title should become `--- My Title`.

I can only edit the following SQL string. There is no possibility to create other functions or likewise.

```
SELECT REPLICATE('_', { fn LENGTH(Lvl) }) + ' ' + Title AS Title
FROM Documents
```

My problem is, that the `LENGTH()` function doesn't work inside the `REPLICATE()` function. Does anybody know why or how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing this in a function or stored procedure?  Your code works fine for me in Query Analyzer.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Lvl, '1', '-') + ' ' + Title as Title
FROM Documents
```

Simply take the `Lvl` column, and replace all instances of 1 with whatever character you want, then concatenate Title to the end of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine for me -

```
select REPLICATE('-',LEN(Lvl)) + ' ' + Title as title from documents
```

Comment: LEN() is no function in the version I'm using... The LENGTH() function does work, as long as it isn't inside the REPLICATE() function.

Comment: @user276289 - Can you tell which version of sql server are you using. I have tested this on SQL server 2005. Your select from question is working fine for me.